# Play Framework Access to MySql Database

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework

I have the following problem:
I have a mysql database and would like to connect to it.
But the following error occurs again and again.

Cannot connect to database[default]

My application conf:
[application.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtLSV.png)

The occuring error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZbVM.png)

I would be very happy about a solution

Comment: Make sure the JDBC url is accessible from the app env.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing the port information in your JDBC url! The format is:

```
jdbc:mysql://[host1][:port1][,[host2][:port2]]...[/[database]]
```

A Sample looks like this:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila?profileSQL=true
```